Justice/ farinets
In Islam i have heard if you were Rude before, it can comeback to you later in life, example if someone was rude against his family, dad, maybe in the futere when he becomes dad it may comeback to him the same, okay so the question is, Does Allah make someone sin just so you can get your justice back ? So you can get payback for what you did in the past if you have not repented
